# how many sequences of non-negative integers

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, integers

For $k\ge n$. How many sequences $a_1,\dots,a_n$ of non-negative integers such that $a_1+\cdots+a_n=k$ are there?
How many of them have $a_i>0$ for all $i$?
How many of them have at least one term equal to $0$?

Comment: See [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Comment: @Lulu how does this relate to stars and bars? could you explain further?

Comment: The article explains the link between sequences and the ways you can choose where to put the bars.

Comment: Not sure where the confusion lies.  This is literally what Stars and Bars is for.  That technique counts $n$ tuples of integers (either positive or non-negative) that sum to $k$ and that is what you are looking for.